# App doesn't start in ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have submitted an painting app on samsungapps.com for Android 2.3.3+ (GingerBeard) for Samsung Galaxy Note only(utilizing it's S-pen). Problem is I have 7-8 buyer's question that the app is not starting(out of 1000+ downloads in 1 week), or crashes immediately. All have one thing in common, they are Android version 4.0. I have tested on Galaxy Note with Android 2.3.4 and on the emulator with Android 4.0; app works the same on both.

I cannot upgrade to ICS as Samsung has not officially rolled out updates for India(for my country), and I am stuck on GingerBeard. So, I cannot test the app on device with ICS.

Also I don't know whether everyone having ICS has problem. I don't know where to start debugging as in emulator it works as expected.

Also app takes sometime to generate all the views, and there are a lot of them; can that be the cause of problem; i.e ICS maybe having shorter wait time for app to give response.

My app also takes quite a chunk of heap, though Galaxy Note has plenty of that(128 MB); maybe update lowered the device's heap size; I don't know about that.

I have asked(replied) to them asking their exact model number, but none replied back. It's very hard to keep customers focused. And their non-English question certainly didn't help. Only 2 English question .

What should I do? Where can I look for possible cause of problems? This is really important as samsung is pushing for ICS on it's all major devices and it is expected soon in India as well, but I don't wanna wait till then. Or should I just not care about these problem.
I don't even know whether this question belongs to SO or not. Please help!

S-layer
http://www.samsungapps.com/topApps/topAppsDetail.as?productId=G00006385310&listYN=Y

Comment: You need a dev with a Note on ICS to run the app and capture the logCat for you... hopefully one will turn up on here!

Comment: Provide a link to your app, I have a SGS2 running ICS. Maybe I´ll have the time tonight to run your app and hopefully get you some more info.

Comment: @Master Chief, Searching for S-layer in Samsung Market does not give me any results. What is the searchable name in the samsung market?

Comment: @Master Chief, I am located in Sweden could be why I can not see your app.

Comment: @Alborz, I have provided the link, it's working for me. Try that. App is released worldwide. It's in productivity section. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the developer console for the stacktraces? If app is crashing and user submits a report you should get them in dev console here:

```
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=<acc_id>#FeedbackOverviewPlace:p=<your package>
```

Comment: I haven't submitted on play.google. It is on samsungapps.com. They doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Then you can use some third-party libraries like BugSense to obtain stacktraces of crashes.